# Why was this question on the difference between Cortisone and Dihydrocortisone deemed off-topic as personal advice?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, advice

How is [The difference between Cortisone and Dihydrocortisone](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/the-difference-between-cortisone-and-dihydrocortisone) deemed off-topic because of personal advices and my "health issues". Those reasons are virtually non-existent. Instead, the question clearly just asks for documented difference between 3 substances. Doesn't need advices at all.

Answer (score 2):

I closed your question as requesting medical advice because you asked about the properties of a drug you yourself are taking in comparison to two other drugs. Stated differently, you requested information about *other treatment options*.

In your question, you mention details about symptoms. As noted in the right sidebar on the main site:

> Do not share personal medical information, medical history or any other specific details about a person's medical symptoms, condition etc (whether yours or someone you know) on this site or any Stack Exchange site.

In the comments, you state:

> the potential for someone to mishandle the displayed use of this drug

It is clear from this comment, that one impetus for the question is whether the use of the drug is appropriate for your personal indication.

In conclusion, it clear that your question is personal medical advice and is thus not appropriate for this site.

Comment: First time I am actually doing this, I have to fully disagree. I have asked the difference between 3 substances that appear to be similar. They are not even drugs per se. The treatment option is just one and it is perfect for the sake of argument.
The question is to establish the difference between 3 hormones and that's just it. The second half of the question is just what made me curious on the subject. I will not and can't do anything with the information gained from a potential answer to the question.

Comment: How could I agree on that? It's literally not what I was doing with this question. I can willfully remove the second half of the question to prevent it from being misinterpreted like that. Personally, I just wanted to understand why a prednisone containing drug is called with an obscure name of a similar hormone and I formulated the question such that it'll be even more helpful.

Comment: @Edenia See Bryan Krause's most recent comment on your question. Even if I accept that the question isn't personal medical advice, it still lacks prior research. One helpful thing to do would be to include a photo of the drug information on the package rather than just telling us what it says.

Comment: @CareyGregory But why would I do that? The question isn't about the drug. I just wanted to know how those 3 substances (not in the context of drugs) differ from one another, because I thought that two of them are somewhat interchangable due to the drug that I am taking.

Comment: That does not make any sense. I think maybe the problem was that this question should not be in medical science, but biology or chemistry.

Comment: @Edenia Of course the question is about the drug. You named the drug and then asked about its contents. Showing us the label would remove all doubts that you got the chemical names correct. And yes, I think the question would have been more appropriate in Chemistry.SE. Since it's closed here you're free to ask it there if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed this personal part of the question (which didn't make it as requesting medical advice by the way), and voted to reopen. The question is clearly:

> What is the theoretical and practical difference between Dihydrocortisone (C21H30O5), Cortisone (C21H28O5) and Prednisone (C21H26O5)? The Wikipedia article about Dihydrocortisone literally consists of one line.

There's nothing personal about it: millions of patients use these medications.

Comment: Also, they are not medications per se, but hormones. I am utterly confused why everyone here are referring to them as medications. Could be either my lack of complete understanding of english terms or the fact it is posted in medical science instead of I don't know - biology. Yes I mentioned a drug called dehydrocortisone, but that part can freely be removed (and it did), as it was kinda irrelevant in essence.

Comment: I have also edited it to make it more suitable for the site (and also voted to re-open now, but agree that the first inception was off-topic). @Edenia what exactly is the answer you are looking for? Are you looking for different potencies of the steroid receptor agonists, are you interested in the biosynthesis or artificial synthesis as the compounds for use in medication? Also, dihydrocortisone is not a standard hormone but as far as I understand the literature a (partially) inactivated metabolite of the cortisone decomposition, and there are multiple different chemicals called dihydroc...

Comment: [cont'd] with the formula C21H30O5 - are you really interested in that compound still or do you want to remove it from the question? I believe it initially was left in there because it was the typo of *dehydrocortisone*.

Answer (score -3):

@IanCampbell rightfully closed this question as a personal medical advice question. As discussed at [Should we edit Personal Medical Advice questions?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1007/7951) edited personal advice questions are still personal advice questions, disguised not to be.

My view is a resounding no.  As pointed out by responses to the linked question,

### no personal advice question, edited or otherwise should be fit for reopening.

Comment: At some point, we need to decide on an official policy about edited personal medical advice questions. Law.SE has a similar problem and is tolerant of edits. See [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice) and [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/excessive-use-of-specific-legal-advice-closure-reason).

Comment: I agree @IanCampbell

Comment: I would strongly suggest to allow edited questions that were, but no longer are personal medical advice. Of course, only if the content truly changed („Should I take Prednisone or Cortisone“ is off-topic, but „What are the pharmacological difference between“ should be on-topic, I would argue. This way, we can empower the „patients“ asking for PMA with general knowledge - which we *can* provide - from which they can obviously benefit. I will try to find some past examples, and maybe we can start a new meta discussion in some time regarding this?

Comment: Interestingly, I [apparently had the exact opposite position 4 years ago](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1009/8212) :D